# In PHP how do I remove a character from a given position in a string

Tags: php, substr

I would like to always delete the character in the 2nd position within a string.  The trouble is, this could literally be anything.

Sample inputs would be:

```
5H23098
SHISL
S-SLSYNSL
M/SHGIKT
```

Output should be:

```
523098
SISL
SSLSYNSL
MSHGIKT
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: two ways i can think of... run two times the substr() (1 char only and 3rd to end) and then combine back the results OR break string into array, set position 1 to null, combine back the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "ASDFGH";
echo substr_replace($str, "", 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s1 = $str[0];
$s2 = substr($str, 2);

$result = $s1.$s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$s = substr($s,0,1).substr($s,2);`

Answer (score 0):

Also it's possible to do:

```
$str = 'abcd';
$str[1] = '';
```

But take into the account that

```
strlen($str) == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "5H23098";

$newString = $string[0].substr($string, 2);
```

Result: 523098

Takes the first character + all characters after position 2.